# Efficient milliseconds display in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas

The goal: find the most CPU efficient way to display the current milliseconds in HTML.

My current solution takes up to 10% CPU computation on my laptop.
My current solution: http://dev.timerintab.appspot.com/test/ms

My final goal is to display the milliseconds on a [timer](http://www.timer-tab.com).

**Update**
I changed the test to take an argument for the interval: http://dev.timerintab.appspot.com/test/ms?interval=x where x is the interval in ms.
 As one can notice an interval of 100ms makes a visual difference in comparison with an interval of 16ms: 
 
http://dev.timerintab.appspot.com/test/ms?interval=100 
 http://dev.timerintab.appspot.com/test/ms?interval=16 
I can even notice a difference between a 20ms and a 16ms interval.

Comment: The human eye wont cope with 1000 changes a second (neither will your screen) so how often do you actually want to update it? Updating every millisecond will just make the counter look like a blur, even if it is achievable.

Comment: do 60 updates per seconds, nobody will notice the difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, don't display every millisecond -- the human eye can't see every hundredth of a second, milliseconds are simply not possible.

Second, use "getMilliseconds()".

Third, don't create a new date in each call to the function. Have two functions:

```
var ms = new Date().getMilliseconds()
var interval = 10;
function periodically(){ ms = new Date().getMilliseconds() }

function quickly(){ 
    ms = ms % 1000;
    domEl.innerHTML = ms<100?(ms<10?'00'+ms:'0'+ms):ms; 
    ms+= interval 
}
setInterval( periodically, 500 );
setInterval( quickly, interval );
```

So, what's happening?
Instead of instantiating a date every time, you have a function which syncs a number to the date every half second. You then have a second function which merely increments that number locally. What happens if they get out of sync? Who cares? They'll sync up in a half second anyway and they won't realistically be off by more than anything the human eye can see anyway.

Comment: Running this script gives me 25% CPU-usage in FF4 and shows ms values above 1000

Comment: nice optimisations you bring here, i like them. and they does make a difference! But i still have a ~5% CPU usage with an interval of 16ms which is a lot for the purpose. You have any other ideas? May be we could update at a lower rate the first digits?

Answer (score 5):

Your display has a refresh rate [probably] of about 60Hz. The human eye sees (consciously, at least) [at less than that rate](http://www.100fps.com/how_many_frames_can_humans_see.htm).

So why are you trying so hard to render a changing numerical figure at 1000Hz? Why not round your figure to the nearest 0.01s? This should be a lot less CPU intensive, and actually be *more* useful to your users who may have more of a shot at actually seeing something.

In fact, in practice, you don't need any greater resolution than 0.1s, which is a doddle.

Comment: an interval of 100ms kinda looks ugly, see for yourself: http://dev.timerintab.appspot.com/test/ms?interval=100 and does make a big difference with a lower intervall, e.g. 16ms: http://dev.timerintab.appspot.com/test/ms?interval=16

Comment: @brillout.com: I get nothing. It's not ugly; what is ugly is numbers flashing so fast that you can't read them _and_ your computer grinds to a half for no reason.

Answer (score 2):

In FF4 your code eats 25% of the CPU usage. Increasing INTERVAL to 50 decreases that usage to 12-15%. Afaik `arguments.callee` spawnes a new interpreter, so use a named function. intializing `setTimeout` every time is not necessary if you use `setInterval`. In that case `arguments.callee` is obsolete too. On my pc these measures (+ setting the interval value to 99) show CPU-usage in FF of <strike>3-5%</strike> 1-3%, in Chrome <strike>around 3%</strike> 0.

```
setInterval(count,INTERVAL);
function count()
{
  var ms = new Date().getMilliseconds() % 1000;
  domEl.innerHTML = ms<100?(ms<10?'00'+ms:'0'+ms):ms;
};
```

Comment: a 99ms interval is kinda ugly, see for yourself: http://dev.timerintab.appspot.com/test/ms?interval=99. but thanks for the hint with arguments.callee

Answer (score 1):

In your example you don't attempt to display every millisecond - you use setTimeout with an interval of 9. Just increasing that interval will (obviously) decrease CPU load while also decreasing the rate at which the time is displayed.

Given this, surely it depends on how often you need the display updating?

I suspect there isn't much more you can do to your script, but I'm willing to be proven wrong!

Comment: yep but an interval of >50ms is kinda ugly and an interval of 16ms looks beautiful. i hope you'll be proven wrong too :-)